# Can't set headers after they are sent in express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I looked around at previous answers to this question, but I don't understand why is this error coming up if there are `res.send()` in multiple paths.

My code is something like this (expressjs 4.13):

```
var user ={
    username: "some",
    password: "a"
}

router.post('/login', authenticate, function (req, res) {
    //if it passes the middleware, send back the user

    var token = jwt.sign({
        username: user.username
    }, jwtSecret);
    res.send({
         token: token,
        user: user
    });
});

function authenticate(req, res, next) {
    var body = req.body;
    var username = body.username, password = body.password;

    //if nothing is sent
    if(!username || !password){
        res.status(400).end('Must send a user and pass');
    }

    //if incorrect credentials are sent
    if(username !== user.username || password !== user.password){
        res.status(401).end("Incorrect credentials");
    }

    //if it reaches here, it means credentials are correct
    next();
}
```

When I don't send anything from my frontend, I am getting the 400 and error message, but my server shows this:

```
POST /apis/auth/login 401 0.841 ms - -
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:346:11)
at ServerResponse.header     (/home/vivek/dev/qwiksplit/jsback/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:718:10)
at ServerResponse.json (/home/vivek/dev/qwiksplit/jsback/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:246:10)
at ServerResponse.send (/home/vivek/dev/qwiksplit/jsback/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:151:21)
at /home/vivek/dev/qwiksplit/jsback/app.js:81:9
at Layer.handle_error (/home/vivek/dev/qwiksplit/jsback/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:71:5)
at trim_prefix (/home/vivek/dev/qwiksplit/jsback/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:310:13)
at /home/vivek/dev/qwiksplit/jsback/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
at Function.process_params (/home/vivek/dev/qwiksplit/jsback/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
at next (/home/vivek/dev/qwiksplit/jsback/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
```

I am not sure how I am setting headers after a response is sent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to return!

```
return res.status(400).end('Must send a user and pass');
```

Comment: That makes sense. I assumed when I say res.send() or res.end(), the execution will stop there and it will be returned by default.

Comment: The response will end but the code after will still be executed http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.end

Comment: To add to that, everything done in Express is 'middleware', even the last callback. So the moment you call `next()` in your `authenticate` middleware, the callback (also middleware) you provided in router.post still runs and tries to run `res.send` as well, even though the response has already been send and that causes the error.

Answer (score 2):

In your middleware function, you need to make sure `next()` is *not* called after you've already sent a response (e.g., by calling `res.send()`, `res.end()` or similar).

The simplest solution is to just return from your middleware right after you've sent a response:

```js
function authenticate(req, res, next) {
    var body = req.body;
    var username = body.username, password = body.password;

    if(!username || !password){
        res.status(400).end('Must send a user and pass');
        return; // <-----
    }

    if(username !== user.username || password !== user.password){
        res.status(401).end("Incorrect credentials");
        return; // <-----
    }

    next();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some return statements. If you don't return from the function `status` and `send` gets called multiple times on your `response` object, and at the end even `next` is called as well, so the upcoming middlewares will operate on the response too.

```
function authenticate(req, res, next) {
    var body = req.body;
    var username = body.username, password = body.password;

    //if nothing is sent
    if(!username || !password){
        res.status(400).end('Must send a user and pass');
        return;
    }

    //if incorrect credentials are sent
    if(username !== user.username || password !== user.password){
        res.status(401).end("Incorrect credentials");
        return;
    }

    //if it reaches here, it means credentials are correct
    next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to add return statement after this code

```
    res.status(400).end('Must send a user and pass');
```

It can be

```
    return; or return res.status(400).end('Must send a user and pass');
```

Just return anything after that line, basically stop execution of your code after that.